# Can the alkyl-oxygen bond in lactones be cleaved in an SN2 reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution, esters

I understand that nucleophiles typically attack the electrophilic carbonyl carbon of the lactone and open the ring through a nucleophilic acyl substitution. Has there ever been the case where the nucleophiles open the lactone ring by attacking the carbon adjacent to the oxygen (not the carbonyl oxygen) via a S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction instead? Is there a preferred pathway for certain nucleophiles to take and why so?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. If you consider the chemistry of a four-membered lactone (a β-lactone), it is able to act as an alkylating agent, as nucleophiles can attack the C–O bond in an S<sub>N</sub>2 fashion.

One example is in the synthesis of a series of β-substituted amino acids ([*J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1985,** *107* (24), 7105–7109](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00310a058)). An intramolecular Mitsunobu reaction of Cbz-protected serine **1** forms the β-lactone **2** which is then opened by a variety of nucleophiles. Here, benzylthiolate is used as an example, giving *N*-Cbz-*S*-benzylcysteine **3** as the product:

[image]

The authors note that:

> Only relatively “hard” nucleophiles like ammonia and methoxide attack the carbonyl to give acyl-oxygen cleavage. In earlier reports serine β-lactones were used mainly for synthesis of seryl peptides by attack of amines at the carbonyl. However, with ammonia as the nucleophile, simply altering the solvent *[from MeCN to THF]* inverts the 3:1 amide/amine ratio.

The following article has a wide selection of more examples (see references 6–8): [*J. Org. Chem.* **2002,** *67* (14), 4680–4683](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo025519n).

Answer (score 2):

The reactivity you describe also occurs in α-lactones. The most common example is the diazotization of amino acids, followed by nucleophilic ring opening (e.g. [*Org. Synth.* **1988,** *66,* 151](https://doi.org/10.15227/orgsyn.066.0151)):

[image: Reaction scheme]

The reaction proceeds with overall retention of configuration, via an initial S<sub>N</sub>2 displacement of N<sub>2</sub> by the carboxylic acid, followed by a second S<sub>N</sub>2 ring-opening at the α-carbon by the nucleophile (here chloride).

See also Organic Chemistry (2nd Ed), Clayden et al., p 875.